# How do I change the color of md-fab button

Tags: html, css, angularjs-material

I've been banging my head to figure out how to customize the default color of the md-fab button and the color which is displayed by hovering over it, yet I cannot seem to find a solution. Applying the classes which usually change the color of buttons doesn't work. I saw that it does change by applying certain material classes to it, but as I said, I want to pick a specific color for it.
Please, help!

My code:

```
 <md-button class="md-fab md-primary md-hue-3" ng-disabled="0>=gains" ng-click="buyTaxi()">
     <md-tooltip md-direction="bottom">Buy a taxi</md-tooltip>
     <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/ic_add_shopping_cart_white_36px.svg"></md-icon>
 </md-button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I just had to add this to the css file:

```
.md-button.md-fab.mybtnstyle {
   background-color: blue;
}
```